# How to check if a variable is set in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this object/array thing:

```
var states = {};

states["CA"] = new State("CA", "California");
states["AR"] = new State("AR", "Arizona");
....
```

How can I check if `states["AL"]` has been set or not? Will the following work (in all browsers)?

```
if (states["AL"] == undefined)
   alert("Invalid state");
```

Comment: Do you want to check whether the value of `states["AL"]` is truly the value undefined or whether it's a "valid" state value (i.e. a non-falsy value)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recommended:

```
if (typeof states["AL"] == 'undefined')
    alert("Invalid state");
```

Litteral `undefined` is possible and will work most of the time, but won't in some browser (IE mac, maybe others).

Comment: undefined should be in quotes?

Comment: Yes, because `typeof` returns a string. However, I'm not sure why using `typeof` is better in the first place.

Comment: @streetpc What if states["AL"] is null?  Then `typeof states["AL"]` will return `"object"` and you won't handle an invalid value correctly.

Comment: @Jonathon: What was asked was whether `states["AL"]` has been set. It being set it to `null` still counts as being set. @Bears: `typeof` is better for two reasons: one, in some older browsers, the global object doesn't have an `undefined` property, and two, because `undefined` is a property of the global object rather than an immutable literal like `null`, it can be inadvertently redefined. For example, a typo in an equality check could do it: `if (undefined = someVar) {...}`.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to do a literal comparison at all; the following will work just fine...

```
if(states["AL"]) 
  alert("State exists"); 
else
  alert("State does not exist");
```

Comment: @Click Yes, if states["AL"] has not been set it will return undefined which will evaluate to false in a boolean expression.

Comment: I would not recommend that for this particular test. What you have above checks if `states["AL"]` is a truthy value or not - for instance `states["AL"]` might be set to `false` but that's different from being undefined.

Comment: @Bears This seems ok to me.  If states["AL"] is any sort of valid value (non-empty string that doesn't evaluate to false), this will handle it fine.

Comment: This checks for true/false. So if `states["AL"]` is zero, it will return false, which is technically not what you want.

Comment: Well, it depends on what the intent of the check is. It sounded like the OP wanted to see whether or not an entry is defined at all - not check to see if it is a falsy value.

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, you could say `if ("AL" in states) { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function State(ab, name){
    if(states && states[ab])return states[ab];

    this.ab=ab;
    this.name=name;
    //whatever else, no return;
}
```